# How to create a button, by clicking a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**So this is the code for the button (btnUser.cs)**

```
public class btnUser : Button
    {
        public int x = 0;
        public int y = 100;
        public int z = 65;
        public btnUser()
        {
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            ForeColor = Color.DarkOrange;
            Location = new Point(x, y);
            Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 10, 0);
            Size = new Size(268, 59);
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        }

    }
```

**And this is how I tried**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            users++;
            BtnUser.btnUser btu = new BtnUser.btnUser();
            btu.Name = "btnUser" + users;
            btu.Text = btu.Name;
            components.Add(BtnUser.btnUser btu.Name);
        }
```

I would like to know the right solution, to automatically popup a button if I click on another one.
*Thanks for the answers* :)

Comment: Whats not working, also there is no magic oneliner you have to create the button name it, put text in, add it to the form or control then position it ect ect

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The `components` collection is used by the WinForm designer and is not intended for your code to use.  If you want to add it to the form, use the form's `Controls` collection.

Comment: Oh yes, the components line was a mistake, I just tried it out.